# returning a dict-like structure from a groupby

Tags: python, python-2.7

here is the basic code:

```
from my_parser import data
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

def grades(date=datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m')):
  this_month = self.data.key_by('GRADE').pop(date) # this gives a list of this month
  monthly = dict(groupby(this_month, lambda k: make_letter(k.GRADE))) # group it by letter grade
  c = [{
    'month': k,
    'total': len(x)
  } for k,x in monthly.iteritems()]
```

however, the dictionary returns like so:

```
A : <itertools._grouper object at 0x1033f0c90>
C : <itertools._grouper object at 0x1033f0c50>
```

is it possible to get it to return more like this, or an alternate tool to do the same concept?

```
{
  A : [ ... ]
  B : [ ... ]
}
```

Comment: in general, the `_grouper` object is a generator, which you can convert to a list (or tuple, if you prefer) by just doing `list(x)`...

Comment: alas, the only problem with this is it does not like to be turned to a list within the list generator I am using. Would I have to cast it to list every time I use it as a variable within the list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
monthly = dict(groupby(this_month, lambda k: make_letter(k.GRADE))) # group it by letter grade
```

try

```
monthly = {
    val:list(items)
    for val,items in
    groupby(this_month, lambda k: make_letter(k.GRADE))
}
```

**Edit:** You may need to pre-sort this_month such that grades are in ascending order (or at least such that all grades corresponding to a given letter appear together).